# only users who create the calendar event should be able to open it and see the details, but i want everyone to see all the events on the calendar

Tags: permissions, calendar

I have many people accessing my calendars, and I want all their added entries to show, but I only want them to be able to double click and open the entries which they themselves made. Now they cannot edit someone else's entry, but they can open it and read that private information. 
Any thoughts???

Comment: Thanks but this does not help.. then only the person who created the vent can see it on the calendar. I want everyone to be able to see all events on the calendar, but not to be able to double-click and open them to see the details in the content form..

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict users to read items created by them. 
Go to list settings-Advance settings and set read access to Read items that were created by the user.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create another calendar and then write a workflow which copies events from your entry calendar to the other one but without details or whatever fields. 
YOu'll need to handle updates which I believe you should be able to do. 
Just add a field on the second calendar called 'ID-org' - set it to the ID of the entry calendar entry and then you can look up the corresponding event on the second calendar. 
There's an issue with handling deletes -you can add a delete option to the entry calendar - field called 'Delete?"  which is yes/no.  Then the workflow could delete the second calendar entry.  Hide the delete buttons from edit and disp forms (easy - just look at the CSS for those buttons via Firefox inspect element (Q)'
You can also use 'speasyforms' google it  - by Joe McShea.  Free and easy to install on a site - you only need full control of the site in question. 
Speasyforms allows you to selectively hide/display fields based on user group permissions (or you can hide to all except the creator and the calendar owners). 
It's really worth investigating - I use it all the time for chores such as you describe. I couldn't do my job without it - it saves me hundreds maybe thousands lines of Javascript since my customer wants a lot of customizations. 
That would be an easier approach and probably the one I would use.